# Custom authorization header headache in swagger 2.0

Tags: node.js, security, swagger-2.0

I am receiving my security tokens for my API using the `Authorization` header param sent like so:

```
Authorization: Bearer <SomeVeryLongTokenThatALegitLoginBegat>
```

The good news is that my node server receives the param allright; I receive it as `args.Authorization.originalValue` in each method in each service in the generated server stubs in `/controllers`. The bad news is that I have a large collection of API endpoints, and I would like to do the authorization of the request before the request gets routed into the controllers.

From what I read, the swagger-security middleware is supposed to do this, but I couldn't get that to work (didn't seem to get into that codeflow at all; see below for what I tried in `$SWAGGER_API_HOME/index.js`).

```
// code snippet from $SWAGGER_API_HOME/index.js
app.use(middleware.swaggerSecurity({
    Authorization: function (req, def, scopes, callback) {
        console.log ('INDEX.JS RECEIVED SOMETHING', req);
        callback();
    }
}));
```

So I do this the tiresome way now, for each method in file in `/controllers/`; an example of this repetitive way follows:

```
exports.userSomethingDELETE = function(args, res, next) {
     /**
     * Do something for user
     * authorization String
     * something SomethingDetails
     * no response value expected for this operation
     **/
    console.log (args.Authorization.originalValue.substring(7));
    var promiseOfAuthentication = performMyOwnAuthentication (args.Authorization.originalValue.substring(7));
    promiseOfAuthentication.then (...)
    ...
}
```

I have a lot of methods (about 500 in all) and so doing the above is very bad way to do auth. I would like the `req` object to be parsed by one auth method and approve before it gets routed to the correct controller. Is there a way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I raised this in swagger-codegen originally and [provided an answer there](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5326). Hope my answer there helps someone.